# Why have wireless controls disappeared from my GNOME topbar?

Tags: wifi, gnome, gnome-shell

I recently upgraded from Fedora 27 to Fedora 28. My version of gnome-shell is `3.28.2-1.fc28`.

Previously, I'm used to having control of wireless networking in the top-bar (right hand side).  It would have a wireless icon.  Clicking gave me a menu that showed the wireless was connected, and gave me options to change the wireless network or wireless settings.

Right now, it doesn't.  I've only got a generic networking icon, the same as for wired networking.  There is no networking item in the menu at all.  (I would have to open GNOME Settings, and then open the wireless settings page).

EDIT: this has happened several times, but other times I do have a wireless networking icon etc. So I guess this is a bug.

EDIT: It seems like logging out and back in again fixes it.

Perhaps it is associated with this message in the system log:

```
Jun 07 18:21:01 alan-laptop gnome-shell[2112]: JS ERROR: TypeError: item is undefined
                                               _activeConnectionChanged@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:371:13
                                               wrapper@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82:22
```

---

The strange thing is, if I connect to a wired network, I actually get a menu item for wired networking.  As before, this has a sub-option which allows editing wired settings.  But apparently I'm not allowed to have this for wireless networking...

Is this is a deliberate change?  If so, is the remaining UI for wired networking an oversight, or is there a deliberate difference?  If this is not deliberate, does anyone know why this happens?  I.e. if it's a bug, does it affect everyone using wireless networking, or are there additional conditions needed to reproduce the bug?

[image: GNOME Top-bar right-side menu, menu has no item for networking, but icons in top-bar show a network connection.] [image: GNOME Top-bar right-side menu, with a menu item for the wired network]

Comment: Is `NetworkManager-wifi` installed?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams yes, `rpm -q` says `NetworkManager-wifi-1.10.8-1.fc28.x86_64`. (Since the issue is intermittent I don't think the problem is I'm missing the package which provides this function. Good question though and I'm very happy to answer it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other users are affected by the same symptoms, and see the same error message.  At least in one other case it is agreed that this does not happen all the time.  It must be a bug, and not a deliberate change.

https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/issues/140

Comment: This seems to be happening randomly on about 1/2 of boots or logins, according to my experience and at least one report.